# Extract Numbers associated with particular phrase

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want to extract group names and associated numbers with that in Python.

Sample Input:

```
34 patients have admitted in hospital and distributed in Pune group with 20 patients, Mumbai group with 10 patients and Nagpur group with 4 patients.
```

Sample Output:

```
'Pune group, 20'
'Mumbai group, 10'
'Nagpur group, 4'
```

Comment: easy just split it and extract any item before "group" and after "with"  and then .join them

Comment: @Lucky Suman, although you have been around for 2+ years here in SO, this is your first question, thus welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to provide what you have tried along with other thing that you have mentioned in the future post. It would still be better if you can show us what regex have you tried here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try that:

```
\b(\S+)\s+group\s+with\s+(\d+)\s+patients
```

In the above regex you get pune as group 1, and patient count as group 2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DPefGn/11)

Sample Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/oGiKEh) ) :

```
import re
regex = r"\s+(\S+)\s+group\s+with\s+(\d+)\s+patients"

test_str = "34 patients have admitted in hospital and distributed in Pune group with 20 patients, Mumbai group with 10 patients and Nagpur group with 4 patients."
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)


for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1)+" group, "+match.group(2));
```